# How do I install the .NET SDK with the Visual Studio Installer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I’d like to install the .NET SDK using the Visual Studio Installer. I selected it in the components list and installed it:

[image]

However, if I try and list the .NET SDKs in either the regular command prompt or the Visual Studio 2022 Command Prompt the ‘dotnet’ command finds nothing. I can install the .NET SDK separately, but I’d like to understand why the Visual Studio Installer isn’t installing it.

[image]

[image]

### dotnet --info

`dotnet --info` yields:

```
C:\Users\tfsagent>dotnet --info

Host:
  Version:      7.0.11
  Architecture: x86
  Commit:       ecb34f85ec

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.22 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.11 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.22 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.11 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.22 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.11 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  x64   [C:\Program Files\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

### Paths

In my `PATH` environment variable, the `dotnet` installations are in this order:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C;C:\Program Files\dotnet`

### dotnet --info for The x64 Installation

If I use a full path to the x64 instance of `dotnet` I get this info:

```
C:\Users\tfsagent>"c:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.401
 Commit:    eb26aacfec

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19045
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\

Host:
  Version:      7.0.11
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       ecb34f85ec

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.401 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.22 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.11 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.22 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.11 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.32 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.22 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.11 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

Further, querying that instance for SDKs *does* yield something:

```
C:\Users\tfsagent>"c:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" --list-sdks
7.0.401 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Is it safe to say that my x86 dotnet runtime is just that: only a runtime? Is it then true that my x64 runtime comes from the .NET 7 SDK?

Comment: This is strange, as VS seems to have (sometimes?) its own copy of the SDK. What's the output of `dotnet --info`? You seem to have _something_ installed at least.

Comment: I gave that a try and posted the output. In my PATH environment variable, the `dotnet` installations are in this order: `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C;C:\Program Files\dotnet\`

Comment: Well, I added a lot more info. I _do_ have an SDK, but it belongs with the x64 version of .net which isn't the default? I'm not sure why.

Comment: Ah! I just read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/deployment/7.0/x86-host-path). Perhaps some piece of software I installed prior to Visual Studio installed the .NET x86 runtime?

Comment: Yea, I guess you've found the culprit there. I've never seen this behavior, but now it makes sense. Just remove the x86 entry from the path, you'll not need it.